# Multidimensional array separators in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I've been searching for a more concise way to represent multidimensional arrays in Javascript, so I'd like to find a way to separate an array using multiple separators, along with Javascript's built-in `string.split(separator)` method.

For example, the string `"what, am, I; doing, here, now"` would become `[["what", "am", "I"],["doing", "here", "now"]]`.

Is there any concise way to implement a function that does this?

```
var theString = "what, am, I; doing, here, now";
var theArray = getArray(theString, [",", ";"]); //this should return [["what", "am", "I"],["doing", "here", "now"]].

function getArray(theString, separators){
    //convert a string to a multidimensional array, given a list of separators
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

LAST EDIT

I was leaving some commas in the words, as @Tom points out.  Here's the final code:

```
var str = "what, am, I; doing, here, now";

var arr = str.split(/\;\s*/g);
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    arr[i] = arr[i].split(/\,\s*/g);
}
console.log(arr);
```

[AND FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/CuaNH/4/)

---

First split on the second separator, then split each member in there on the other separator.

```
var str = "what, am, I; doing, here, now";

var arr = str.split(';');
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    arr[i] = arr[i].split(' ');
}
```

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CuaNH/)

Note that you'll have to do a tad bit of cleanup to remove the empty space in the second array, but that should be simple.

---

EDIT -- I was feeling energetic - here's how you kill that annoying leading space

```
var str = "what, am, I; doing, here, now";

var arr = str.split(';');
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    arr[i] = arr[i].replace(/^\s*/, '').split(' ');
}
```

[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/CuaNH/1/)

---

EDIT - this is why I love SO so much.  Per @Nathan, you can just split on the regex and save some trouble

```
var str = "what, am, I; doing, here, now";

var arr = str.split(/\;\s*/g);
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    arr[i] = arr[i].split(' ');
}
console.log(arr);
```

[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/CuaNH/2/)

Comment: It would be best if the function would work correctly for any number of separators (not just one or two) - this would offer a greater amount of flexibility.

Comment: @AndersonGreen - for sure - it should be simple for you to generalize the above code into a function that accepts the delimiteres as parameters :)

Comment: Are there any other concise ways of representing multidimensional arrays in Javascript (besides this one)? I want to avoid "re-inventing the wheel", if possible.

Comment: @AndersonGreen - not sure.  I think this is about the standard way to break a string into an array based on a delimiter.  What did you have in mind?

Comment: To remove the space, you could also just split on `'; '` the first time.

Comment: @Xymostech - absolutely.  If you know there's always going to be a space after the first delimiter, then I'd say that's the preferable way

Comment: You can split on a regex. If you split by `/\;\s*/g` to begin with, you don't have to `replace(/^\s*/, '')` later.

Comment: @Nathan that's genius - thanks - I would have never thought of that.  Updated my answer.

Comment: @AdamRackis: it should be `[["what", "am", "I"],["doing", "here", "now"]]` and you are returning `[["what,", "am,", "I"],["doing,", "here,", "now"]]` (note the comma inside string)

Comment: This answer is impressively concise. However, it would be a bit easier to understand if it were encapsulated inside a function (with the parameters `str` and `separators`).

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
var theString = "what, am, I; another, string; doing, here, now";
 //this should return [["what", "am", "I"],["doing", "here", "now"]].

function getArray(theString, separators){
    //Firs split
    var strings = theString.replace(/\s+/g, '').split(separators.pop());
    //Second split
        var sep = separators.pop();
        for (var i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
            strings[i] = strings[i].split(sep);
        };
    console.log(strings);
    return strings;
}

var theArray = getArray(theString,["," ,";" ]);
```

#### Update:

Now the code should work: http://jsfiddle.net/beTEq/1/

Comment: Did you test this? Because I'm fairly certain this doesn't work.

Comment: He's right.  Even if you include a `return strings` in the function, it doesn't quite work  http://jsfiddle.net/beTEq/

Comment: @TomSarduy The function "getArray" returns `undefined`, but it should return the variable `strings` as well as printing it to the console. All you need to do now is add `return strings;` after the last line in the function `getArray`, so that it will work correctly.

Comment: @AndersonGreen: Yes, I forgot that, I was very focused in the console output

Comment: @TomSarduy Also, it appears that it won't work when there are more than two separators - it might be fairly easy to fix this, though.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out [a solution](http://jsfiddle.net/mu2gU/) that can handle any number of separators, based on [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16503849/975097).

```
function getArray(theString, separators) {
    separators = separators.reverse();
    var theArray = theString.split(separators[0]);
    for (var j = 1; j < separators.length; j++) {
        theArray = theArray.map(function mapper(v, i, a) {
            if (typeof v == "string") {
                return v.split(separators[j]);
            } else {
                return v.map(mapper);
            }
        });
    }
    return theArray;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(getArray("A, b, c; d, e, f;g,h,i'a, b, c;d,e,f", [",", ";", "'"])));
//this will write [[["A"," b"," c"],[" d"," e"," f"],["g","h","i"]],[["a"," b"," c"],["d","e","f"]]] to the console.
```