# Split an array of strings using a separator

Tags: javascript, string, split

In JavaScript, is it possible to split each string in a multidimensional array of strings using a separator? I'm trying to split a multidimensional array of strings using a string separator, but I don't yet know how to iterate over a multidimensional array without using multiple for-loops.

```
var theArray = [["Split,each"],["string, in"],["this, array"]];
```

As far as I know, it isn't possible to apply the `string.split(",")` method to a multidimensional array. I'll need to find a workaround, since this code isn't valid:

```
alert([["Split,each"],["string, in"],["this","array"]].split(","));
```

Comment: And what should your result be? An array of 3 arrays, or an array of 6 strings?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski The result should be an array of 3 arrays, where each of the 3 arrays is an array of strings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the Array `map` method to return a modified version of your array:

```
var newArray = theArray.map(function(v,i,a){
   return v[0].split(",");
});
```

The function that is passed as the argument to the `map` method is used to determine the values in the mapped array. As you can see, the function takes each value in the array, splits it by comma, and returns the resulting array of two strings.

The output is then:

```
[["Split", "each"],["string", "in"],["this", "array"]];
```

To make this work  recursively for arrays of arbitrary depth, you can use:

```
var newArray = theArray.map(function mapper(v,i,a){
    if(typeof v == "string"){
        return v.split(",");
    } else {
        return v.map(mapper);
    }
});
```

Comment: No need to include `i` and `a`, they're redundant variables. Also, `map` isn't supported in versions of IE < 9.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville Yes, added those from habit.

Comment: I keep getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'split'` http://jsfiddle.net/4Psmt/

Comment: @AndersonGreen You copied the code just a second too early. I modified `v` to `v[0]`, since the elements in your array are arrays.

Comment: @AndersonGreen I've added a recursive version if you're interested.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using a traditional for loop:

```
var theArray = [["Split,each"],["string, in"],["this","array"]];

for(var i = 0; i<theArray.length; i++) {
    theArray[i] = theArray[i].split(",");
}
```

I'd steer clear of using the `map` method, [it doesn't have great support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Browser_compatibility). (IE < 9 doesn't support it)

Comment: This doesn't work for multidimensional arrays of any dimension. It only works for 2-dimensional arrays.

Comment: You only provided an example with a 2-dimensional array. Use recursion to iterate through multi-dimensional arrays. I will provide an example of this technique in my answer.

Comment: I still don't see a recursive iteration technique here. Is this part still a work in progress?